# How to change the render order of UIImageViews created in Storyboard

Tags: ios, user-interface, uiview, uiimageview, swift4

I am working on an iPhone application using Swift 4 which creates characters.

About this application: on the Storyboard I created some UIImageViews that render on top of each other which represent some parts of the character such as socks, shoes, pants, shirts. I then combine all these layers in the code to create the full character. I have buttons in the user interface to choose a category. When a category is chosen, I display all possible items the character can wear in a UICollectionView. The user then selects an item from this collection and so the corresponding image changes accordingly.

The problem: since I have created these UIImageViews on top of each other using the Storyboard already, they already have an order while rendering. But sometimes the items have to render in a different order. For example, sometimes shoes have to render on top of pants as in wearing a skinny jeans, while other times shoes have to render under the pants as in wearing a bootcut jeans. Sometimes the user doesn't want to bring a layer all the way to the top but between some certain layers.

I want to give the users the ability to change the render order of items or move them a layer up or down.

What would be a good approach to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance for the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A UIView renders it child views from first to last. Thus the rear subviews cover the front subviews. There are several methods to change the order of subviews. You may use [`bringSubview(toFront:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622541-bringsubview).

```
view.bringSubview(toFront: shoeView)
```

Will render the subview `shoeView` at last such that is on top of all other subviews of `view`.

If you want to move a view, you might use [`insertSubview(_:at:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622538-insertsubview). If the view always a subview, it is simply moved to the new index.

Comment: @celemens, this is helpful, but what I need is a way to put a layer in between two layers, or exactly after Xth layer. This doesn't exist, right? We have to write our own.

Comment: @tiw: I've extended my post.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to do it programmatically, and I think the best way is to keep `@IBOutlet`s to those `UIImageView`s and then at the appropriate time just switch their order in their `superview.subviews` - the view uses the order of it's subviews to determine the order of rendering them.

So just to illustrate a short example:

```
@IBOutlet var shoesImageView: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var pantsImageView: UIImageView!

@IBAction func putShoesOnTop() {
    let superView = shoesImageView.superview!
    superView.bringSubview(toFront: shoesImageView)
}

@IBAction func putPantsOnTop() {
    let superView = pantsImageView.superview!
    superView.bringSubview(toFront: pantsImageView)
}
```